# query returns only one row when using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Hello all I have the following php code. Purpose of it is to select users from seviral groups administrators, accountants ets. Problem is that I am getting users only from one group. But want to select them all.

```
<?
include 'connect/connect.php';
class Model_authorization extends Model
{
    public function get_data()
    {    
        $connect=new createCon();
        $login = "SELECT id, Email, Passwords
                FROM user u
                INNER JOIN user_GroupUser ug ON u.ID = ug.User_id
                WHERE ug.group_id in(1,2)
                ";
        $k= mysqli_query( $connect->connect(),$login);
            if (!$k) {
                echo 'MySQL Error: ' . mysqli_error();
                exit;
             }
             $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($k);
echo var_dump($data);
             if ($_POST){
            if($data['Passwords'] === ($_POST['Pass']) &&  $data['Email'] === ($_POST['Email']))
            {

                //setcookie($data['id']);
               // header("Location: main_view.php"); exit();
                return array(
                        'Year' => $data['id']
                    // todo
                );
            }
            else {
                return array(
                        'Year' => 0

                    // todo
                );
            }
                }
    }
}
?>
```

I have checked the query using phpmyadmin and there it worked properly. So I think that problem is in my PHP code. But can't figure out where.

Comment: Try to `echo $k` before `mysqli_fetch_assoc`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mysqli_fetch_assoc` returns an associative result of one row. See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)

You need to do something like this:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $data[] = $row;
}
```

that will give you an array of associative arrays of query results.

Answer (score 0):

you are currently only fetching the first row in your result set. 
The mysqli_fetch_assoc only returns one row according to [fetch-assoc man page](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php), so you need a loop to actually go through all results.

Answer (score 0):

How many rows is your query returning?
If you have to browse multiple rows you should do this:

```
while ($data = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    //do your stuff
}
```